# Galaxy Tab 3: How to get it to make use of the MicroSD card?

Tags: insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to Android tablets. Anyway, I have a Galaxy Tab 3 with only 16GB built it, and of course I've hit the point where I'm running out of space. So I bought a 32GB MicroSD card, and assumed that would solve the problem. However, the tablet doesn't seem to want to make use of it, especially when it comes to moving over apps and data that are already on the device. And I'm totally lost as to how to make it move at least some of that stuff over, as well as when it comes to setting it to use the card as the main storage on anything new from this point forward.

Can anyone explain to me just what I need to do to make this silly thing start using the card? I've totally hit the limit of the built-in 16GB, and don't even have enough room left to save new photos, much less update apps or install new ones. No matter what I try to adjust in the settings, it just won't make the switch, and I'm totally lost at this point.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things for you to check out:

- our [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) gives you some general information, background, and first aid on the storage problem
- our [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) will let you know about moving apps to your shiny new SD card
- your camera app will certainly have an option to tell it where to save new photos/videos – set that to your new card. If it does not, there are [plenty of alternatives](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera) available. For some specific recommendations, see [Camera software for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18931/185) on our sister site.

Comment: Always glad to help, ald! If you find an answer helpful, you can always "upvote" it (click the `^` next to it) – that's called an "SE-style thanks" :) If it solves your issue (or appears to be the most useful answer to your question), you should "accept" it (clicking the check-mark next to it).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I can't upvote yet. I'm sill a noob and don't have 15 upvotes yet. 

Comment: Oh – sorry, so long ago for me. Though that didn't apply to answers given on your own questions...